# geany: on new line, ignores indentation

Tags: cursor, geany

I have a problem with `geany` when I press enter to start a new line (I am programming with python):

```
if res[index][0]==0:
      temp=0 |
```

(The "|" indicates the postition of the cursor).

When I press enter to go to a new line, the cursor moves right under `temp=0` as it should, then after half a second it moves to the extreme left of the line, ignoring the `python indentation`.

Have I changed something in the settings??

I use `geany 1.23.1` and `Lubuntu 14.04.1`.

Comment: Try disabling all plugins  to make sure its not one of those.
I use Geany for my python code daily and never had such a problem (currently on same version of Geany on Ubuntu 14.04.1).

Comment: Thanks, disabling the `autosave plugin` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

@NGRhodes: You were right, the `autosave plugin` was causing the problem. I just deactivated it and now the cursor behaves in a normal way.

I just found out that the bug was reported almost three years ago but still not solved!!
http://sourceforge.net/p/geany/bugs/835/

### EDIT

I have found the real origin of the problem: Edit tab->Preferences->Files->Saving Files->"Strip trailing spaces and tabs". If you tick that option then don't use the auto-save, and vice-versa, or you'll see the problem appear.